# What type of bird is this?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

Can someone identify this white colour bird?

Location: unknown (image taken from someone's profile pic).

Comment: Please comment about the location where you found the bird / where this picture was taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the picture, it looks like ***[Cacatua sulphurea](http://www.arkive.org/yellow-crested-cockatoo/cacatua-sulphurea/)***

[image]

<sup>[[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow-crested_cockatoo#/media/File%3AGelbwangenkakadu_8559.jpg)]</sup>

> The yellow-crested cockatoo (*Cacatua sulphurea*) also known as the lesser sulphur-crested cockatoo, is a medium-sized (approximately 34 cm long) cockatoo with white plumage, bluish-white bare orbital skin, grey feet, a black bill, and a retractile yellow or orange crest. The sexes are similar.[[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow-crested_cockatoo#/editor/0)]

**Habitat and ecology:**

- It mostly inhabits evergreen, deciduous, monsoon and semi-evergreen forests.
- It nests in tree cavities or a pre-existing hole made by any another species.(Nandika *et al.*)
- Observations made on Masakabing Island suggests that it's favourite diet include male fruits of *Artocarpus communis*, flowers and fruits of *Cocos nucifera*, Young leaves and flowers of *Ceiba petandra*, mangroves and male fruits of *Brassus sudaica*.(Metz *et al.*)
- It mostly nests on *C. nucifera*, *A. communis*, *C. petandra*, *Tamarindus indica* and *Avicennia* sp. (Nandika *et al.*)
  [[Source](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/22684777/0)]

**Why it is not *Cacatua galerita*?**

- The plumage is different and the skin around the eyes are more white. [[Source: In description part](http://www.arkive.org/yellow-crested-cockatoo/cacatua-sulphurea/)]
- In the picture of the OP there is a blue ring over the eyes and it is also known as blue-eyed cockatoo. [[Source: In the description part](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulphur-crested_cockatoo)]

Comment: I don't know where the OP's photo was taken, but I assume it is a pet bird. The yellow-crested cockatoo is classified as a critically endangered species, so it's rather unlikely someone would own it as a pet.

Comment: @adjan But from the plumage it still looks like *Cacatua sulphurea*

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's a [sulphur-crested cockatoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulphur-crested_cockatoo) (*Cacatua galerita*). It is a quite common pet bird.

[image]

Image source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cacatua_galerita_Tas_2.jpg